# Search a JSON using Retrofit 2.0

Tags: android, json, gson, retrofit, retrofit2

I googled a lot of tutorials on using Query, but none of them seems to work. Say a Json array contains objects with variables {a, b, c}, and there are 100 such objects. How do a conduct a filtered search in the Json, on the criteria say, a=something, (in SQLite we would use "a LIKE?" "search_criteria"), so that the list we receive contains only the filtered results.

Comment: `Retrofit` is a library for making HTTP requests. I am not sure you what you're looking for but from what I can understand, its not possible. JSON is a string which is then parsed into objects, list of objects. You'll have to search in that.

Comment: Exactly. Either you'd need to iterate through every of those objects or to make a call to the API that returns filtered results instead. The question is, is the API yours?

Comment: Okay thank you for the suggestions. But I don't know how to make an API to return filtered results. Can somebody show me an example or comment a link.

Comment: That's too broad a request. You've given no information about what type of server you are running. Generally speaking, you need to use URL query parameters and filter the data server side

Comment: @Uday Technically OkHttp makes the HTTP requests. Retrofit is a wrapper that converts the Response objects into Java objects for different endpoints

Comment: @cricket_007 The point i was making is how is the OP's question related to Retrofit.

Answer (score 0):

Best way to do this on Server Api Call.

Get Method: **www.example.com/api/v1/getSample?a=5** 

In Retrofit: `Call<ResponseBody> getSample(@Query("a") int a);`

Comment: That entirely depends on the functionality of the API to accept a query parameter. It won't just work like that

Comment: Does the query value definitely need to be int? I was trying the same statement as @Querry("a") String value, and it did not work.